# How to fix 'stdio.h' file not found on VScode

Tags: clang, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

Recently I upgraded to Big Sur(11.4).
When i try to code in VS code in C i get the warning 'stdio.h' file not found
and when I try to compile it I get the error

```
main.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~
```

But if I use the terminal and use clang it compiles just fine.Its the same in case of c++ i get the error

```
 In file included from x.cpp:1:
 In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
 In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:214:
 In file included from /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
 /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not 
 found
 #include_next <wchar.h>
```

Xcode is working fine it is also compiling with gcc but getting the error in VS code only.
This is my c_cpp_properties.json file

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Mac",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/11.1.0/include/c++/v1"

        ],
        "defines": [],
        "macFrameworkPath": [],
        "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++14",
        "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

and this is the task.json file

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang"
    }
]
}
```

I also have xcode and command line tools install

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

to your includePath. You can check the gcc include path that terminal is using by running the following line in terminal

```
echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -
```